# Retrofit: значения по умолчанию несуществующих полей

Tags: java, android, kotlin, retrofit

Использую **Retrofit** для получения данных.
Создал свой класс, в который эти данные записываются.
Кроме тех полей, что есть уже в JSON'е мне надо еще одно мое кастомное поле типа boolean, которое по умолчанию должно быть true.
Но ни оно, ни любое другое поле со значение по умолчанию не ставится.
Если boolean то false. Если int, то 0. Если string то null

```
    data class MyClass(
        // основные поля, которые работают хорошо
        var isWork: Boolean = true,
        var test: String = "sdfgsdfg",
        var xx: Int = 45
    )

////////////
isWork=false, test=null, xx=0)
```

Пробовал переписать это в init - не помогло.

```
data class MyClass(        
    var isWork: Boolean,
    var test: String,
    var xx: Int
) {
    init {
        isWork = true
        test = "sdfgsdfg"
        xx = 45
    }
}
```

Я понимаю, что **Retrofit** не находит этих полей в заданном Json'е и ставит их по умолчанию сам.
Как **мне** задать нужные значения для этих полей?

```
interface ApiGetCashellable {


    @GET("https://belarusbank.by/api/kursExchange")
    fun giveMeYourMoney(): Call<MutableList<BelarusBankClass>>


    companion object {

        @JvmStatic
        fun create(): ApiGetCashellable {
            val okHttpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .connectTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .writeTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .readTimeout(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .build()
            val retrofit: Retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("https://belarusbank.by/")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .client(okHttpClient)
                .build()
            return retrofit.create(ApiGetCashellable::class.java)
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Вообще-то Retrofit - это вроде менеджера работы с сетью. Запросы шлёт OkHttp, ответы в объекты преобразует подключенный конвертер - вот его фамилия здесь больше интересна. Также интересен пример json-строки и как выглядит API-интерфейс

Comment: @woesss дополнил топик интерфейсом. json можно посмотреть в GET. но мне кажется ни интерфейс ни сам json тут не причем. ДА! можно изменить значение по умолчанию, уже после получения ответа от сервера. но это пахнет костылями. ведь так придется делать каждый раз при запросе данных с сервера. можно ли как-то впихнуть значение по умолчанию 1 раз?

Comment: Gson написан на java и не учитывает особенности котлина - если вам не принципиально посмотрите [Moshi](https://github.com/square/retrofit/tree/master/retrofit-converters/moshi). Хотя технически первый пример должен работать как надо - всем свойствам присвоены дефолтные значения, значит конструктор без параметров, нужный Gson-у будет создан. Единственное подозрение - если этот дата-класс вложен в другой класс - тогда условие не соблюдается из-за скрытой ссылки на внешний класс.

Comment: @woesss нет, это не вложенный класс. он и на init{...} никак не реагирует.

Comment: BelarusBankClass - это ваш dto класс. Предлагаю создать еще один класс, аля BelarusBankDataItem, сделать конвертор с BelarusBankClass в BelarusBankDataItem, который дополнить своими полями

Comment: @Serj можно просто написать метод, который после запроса в инет буде обрабатывать заведомо отсутствующие поля. но это все костыли!) интересен момент "а можно без костылей?". я ведь делаю запрос. данное поле не находится. надо выставить ТО значение, которое Я указал.

Comment: Вам сюда https://futurestud.io/tutorials/gson-advanced-custom-instance-creator